# How to insert a space delimited text file into mysql using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, parsing

**My text file looks like this:**

```
10May2013   3.1   http://ncbi.org p.sojae_aafeatureimp    p.sojae_aafeatureimp

10May2013   3.2   http://ncbi.org   p.sojae_aasequenceimp   p.sojae_aasequenceimp

10May2013   3.3   http://ncbi.org   p.sojae_blatalignment   p.sojae_blatalignment
```

How can I parse and insert these seperate rows into my DB?

**DB structure: (date, version, url, name, description)**

I have to insert the values from the text file to mysql using Python. So far my script is like:

```
import MySQLdb, csv, sys
with open('externaldatabase.txt') as textfile:
  csvreader = csv.reader(textfile)
  csvdata = []
  for row in csvreader:
  csvdata.append(row)

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "username", passwd = "password",db = "database_name")
c = conn.cursor()

for row in csvdata:
# Insert a row of data

c.execute("INSERT INTO externaldatabase (release_date, version, download_url, name, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (row))

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

But its getting me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "csv1.py", line 16, in <module>

c.execute("INSERT INTO externaldatabase (release_date, version, download_url, name, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (row))

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: this isn't a forum where people do things for you. Put forth some effort. What did you try?

Comment: Please check my post once again. I posted the coding that I have done so far. I am a novice but have to complete this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the delimiter to csv.reader function:

```
csvreader = csv.reader(textfile, delimiter='\t')
```

You didn't do it in your code, so Python doesn't split the line of your CSV file. That's why it gives the error.

---

If you have the file with all the columns of MySQL table, you can use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) 
command. It's much faster, then loading line by line.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'externaldatabase.txt'
INTO TABLE database_name.externaldatabase
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```